# Disable this popup intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

What is it telling me and how do I turn this off?

[image]

How do I turn this off?

Also I turned this on:

[image]

but I still have to click my mouse and hold it to see type info. Anyone know what might be overriding this?

I'm following this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-scala-code.html#d211606e205

But what is N/A for mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside a block which is passed to a function as an argument for [by-name parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html). You may turn off this popup completely or only for arguments in curly braces (block expressions):

[image]

Type info popup is probably also missing because of it.